# Is there an R function to reduce the same sets of code for different data sets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, repeat

Is there a function where I can reduce the line of repeated plot codes for different data sets?

```
plot_missing(prospects6K, 
             group = c("Excellent" = 0.01, "Good" = 0.3, "Ok" = 0.6, "Bad" = 0.9),
             missing_only = T,
             title= "Missing User Data",
             ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
             theme_config = list(legend.position = c("bottom"))
)

plot_missing(testing5K, 
             group = c("Excellent" = 0.01, "Good" = 0.3, "Ok" = 0.6, "Bad" = 0.9),
             missing_only = T,
             title= "Missing User Data",
             ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
             theme_config = list(legend.position = c("bottom"))
)

plot_missing(training15K, 
             group = c("Excellent" = 0.01, "Good" = 0.3, "Ok" = 0.6, "Bad" = 0.9),
             missing_only = T,
             title= "Missing User Data",
             ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
             theme_config = list(legend.position = c("bottom"))
)
```

Comment: lapply would be an option. Or a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with data frames, first create a list of them:

```
plot_list <- list(prospects6K, testing5K, training15K)
```

Then you can use lapply:

```
lapply(plot_list, \(x) plot_missing(x, 
             group = c("Excellent" = 0.01, "Good" = 0.3, "Ok" = 0.6, "Bad" = 0.9),
             missing_only = T,
             title= "Missing User Data",
             ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
             theme_config = list(legend.position = c("bottom"))
)
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `lapply(plot_list, \(x) plot_missing(x,`. And the rest seems to work.